# Can you add affiliate links to 'share' URLs?

Tags: facebook, share

can anyone let me know if it is possible to add a dynamic URL to a Facebook share website link. So for example would I be able to add an affiliate tracking link to the share URL when a users elects to share one of the items from my store to their facebook page?

I would like to be able to reward users commission if someone see's the share link and then buys the product from my store.

Answer (score 0):

When sharing a link on facebook, it will most likely output 4 things.

1. An image
2. The title of the webpage
3. The URL found after all redirects
4. A short description

The image and the bold title of your post will have the link you shared, but the URL mentioned in (3) will have a new URL.

With Facebook's sharer.php you can share any URL (urlencoded):

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fclkde.tradedoubler.com%2Fclick%3Fp%3D139965%26a%3D1820176%26g%3D18881802